# react-laravel Unexpected token

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5, react-laravel

I am trying to get react-laravel working. I have installed everything correctly (v8js etc) but I keep getting:

```
V8Js::executeString():18903: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The problem seems to be with my component.js file:

```
var Application = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="Networks">
                <ul>
                    <li>Test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

---

Also, is it possible to use ES6?

---

My view:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>JSPM Experiment</title>
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/react-laravel/react.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/components.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/react-laravel/react_ujs.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='react-root'>
</div>
@react_component('Application',[ 'title' => 'Hello, World' ], [ 'prerender' => true ])
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about your build pipeline - how are you transpiling it to ES5? I assume babel with the react preset and es2015 presets?

Comment: The provided code seems perfectly fine. The problem must lie elsewhere. *PS: Go for the eyes Boo!*

Comment: I have added my view :)

Comment: @DominicTobias These is no build process, it just loads stuff on the fly

Comment: Don't you need to put your HTML in quotes in your return? `return('<div ... </div>')`

Answer (score 0):

Is it "component.js" or "components.js"? You likely have a typo.

Usually you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when trying to load a javascript file that doesn't exist. Laravel renders a 404 HTML page and the first `<` trips up your script tag.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has still this error, I installed Laravel 6 and set up React:

```
php artisan preset react
npm install
```

And then I got a similar error "Syntax Error: Unexpected token" as the React JSX syntax didn't seem to be understood. It got fixed by altering babel config in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.babelConfig({
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with Laravel 6. Please check your **webpack.mix.js** file, it should be `mix.react()` instead of `mix.js()`

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#react